# JQGrid Does Not Return Large Set Of Data From Server

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, jqgrid

When I use `jqgrid` and want to render `more than 5000 records` in grid, `no response body is returned from server` which is very strange. I have Stored Procedure which returns 15000 records from database. Then from backend C# code I call this procedure and then I return the set in type List of entity type in JsonFormat to client. When I return small set for example 100, there is no problem. Body reponse is returned in json format, but when I work with large sets no response is returned. What do you think ?

**javascript:**

```
jQuery("#accounts #tranGrid").jqGrid({
            url: ncb.NCB + "/Home/GetBillingTransasctions",
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ['BillingTransactionID', 'AccountID'],
            colModel: [
                 {
                    name: 'BillingTransactionID', index: 'BillingTransactionID', sortable: false, align: 'left',
                    editable: true, edittype: 'text', resizable: true, hidden: true, viewable: false
                 },
                 {
                    name: 'AccountID', index: 'AccountID', sortable: false, align: 'left',
                    editable: true, edittype: 'text', resizable: true, hidden: true, viewable: false
                 }
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#tranPager',
            sortname: 'BillingTransactionID',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc"
        }).navGrid("#tranPager", { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
```

**C# code**

```
 var obj = new {
                total = pTotal,
                page,
                records = Manager.GetBillTranCount(accountID),
                rows = Manager.GetAllBillTranPaged(sRowIndex, eRowIndex, sidx, sord, accountID)
        };

    return new JsonResult() { Data = obj, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

Comment: Can you tell what is the error that you see in the browser console?

Comment: There is no error which is very strange.

Comment: ok, if you inspect the browser request what do you see as the response?